# Redefining index of a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have an example list

```
['i,am,a,dog,i,am,a,king,king,is,god,god,made,humans,dog,loves,humans']
```

The problem is that all the words are on the same index. Please suggest how can we convert it into a proper list with all words at different indexes.

Apologies in advance as I don't know how to frame the title for this issue.

result:

```
['i','am','a','dog','i','am','a','king','king','is','god','god','made','humans','dog','loves','humans']
```

Comment: Try mylist[0].split(‘,’)

Comment: Additionally, this is very basic Python data structure manipulation.  I recommend taking a Python tutorial as this will give you the foundation you will need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
my_list = ['i,am,a,dog,i,am,a,king,king,is,god,god,made,humans,dog,loves,humans']
new_list = mylist[0].split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
splitted_list = single_index_list[0].split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
L = ['i,am,a,dog,i,am,a,king,king,is,god,god,made,humans,dog,loves,humans']
L[0].split(',')
```

split(',') will split your single index string to multiple strings